# Proper way to get my twitter feed with a PHP script with latest protocol

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

What is the proper way to include a twitter feed (last 5 tweets) on my Bootstrap website with the latest protocol version?

Comment: https://github.com/andrewbiggart/latest-tweets-php-o-auth/blob/master/tweets.php

Comment: @cillosis what is the difference between https://github.com/andrewbiggart/php-tweet and the one you sent me?

Comment: Nothing, other than I linked to a specific file. I copied the link from a quick Google search.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest Twitter 1.1 API

The JavaScript Way: http://codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/Ioype

and

The PHP way: https://github.com/andrewbiggart/latest-tweets-php-o-auth

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.